# Spree - how to add multiple products to cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have created a semi-custom Addon function for products. I created a new relationship table in the backend which connects one product to another product (through a checkbox and an ajax request in the backend).

What I am having trouble with is how to manipulate the populate_orders_path so that I can pass various variant/product id's to the cart at the same time.

Currently in my cart form partial I have this:

```
  <div id="product-addons" class="col-md-6">
    <h3 class="product-section-title">Add Ons</h3>
    <%= image_tag('short-line-2.png', class: 'hundy') %>
    <% addons = Addon.where(product_id: @product.id) %>
    <% addons.each_with_index do |a, index| %>
        <%= a.inspect %>
        <% product_addon = Spree::Product.where(id: a.product_addon_id).first %>
        <% addon_variant = Spree::Variant.where(product_id: a.product_addon_id).first %>
        <% addon_image = Spree::Asset.where(viewable_id: addon_variant.id).first %>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <%= image_tag('/spree/products/' + addon_image.id.to_s + '/mini/' + product_addon.images[0].attachment_file_name) %>
          <%= check_box_tag "products[#{a.id}][]", addon_variant.id, index == 0 %>

          <span style="margin-left: 6px;"><%= product_addon.name %></span>
          <br/>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

But I am not sure what to do with
`<%= hidden_field_tag "variant_id", @product.master.id %>` in order for it to use multiple ID's. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get above functionality by Spree promotion.
Configure the item added to cart rule and add another item to cart by action in promotion section.

it will work like this if Variant A is added to cart then Variant B will be added to cart automatically.

Comment: I did have a look at the promotion functionality. There will be 3 products showing in the checkbox's to choose from so the customer could choose 0 or he could choose all 3. Would that work in this situation?

Comment: That promotion can be configure as n number of combinations. i.e if 2 items added in cart then give another item or if 1 item added to the cart then give 2 products or if combination of 3 products is in cart then give 100 rs off like wise. you need to explore the spree promotions.

Comment: They are addons. So like, a customer would add a box of chocolates or a gift card to their order. If I do it with promotions I would need multiple different variants and multiple different promotions to make it work?